# Ms Office Communicator text formating

Tags: office-communicator-2007

How to send highlighted text message using MS office Communicator 2007.
I have seen people sending messages `in this Format` as highlighted.

I tried to search on internet but not able to find any answer for this
Is there any shortcut key that Communicator provides for sending Highlighted text?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you format text before sending it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/create-and-send-an-instant-message-HA010290005.aspx#BM5